# Problem of a string read in function system() (probably due to a bad malloc)

Tags: c, string, malloc, system, strcat

```
chain1 = (char *) malloc(5*sizeof(char*) + 1);
                strcat(chain1, "cp mediaPlayer.exe ");
                strcat(chain1, actual->chain);
                strcat(chain1, "\n");
```

system(chain1);

Hi everyone, i have an issue with my actual string... I'm trying to create a string that will be used in the function system that is called by the shell on my linux but the fact is that it can read my string because it doesn't start with cp mediaPlayer.exe but this --> sh: 1: ��P�Pcp:
Then, the error below is sent to me on my shell and i really don't know how to fix it.

sh: 1: ��P�Pcp: not found

I'm on it for 2 days but i just couldn't find a solution if someone can help me ? Thanks by the way !

Comment: Please explain `5*sizeof(char*) + 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
chain1 = (char *) malloc(5*sizeof(char*) + 1);
```

This will allocate enough space for five character *pointers* plus an extra byte. A pointer is not the same as a character, it tends to be either four or eight bytes currently but can actually be any size. You probably want `sizeof(char)` but, since that's always 1, you can just ignore it in multiplications.

You probably also want a number higher than five since that's not even enough to store your fixed prefix.

In addition, the current *content* of that allocated block will be arbitrary so `strcat` is *not* the first operation you should be performing on it (since that requires a valid C string).

This is almost *certainly* the cause of your "string starts with rubbish" problem. A `strcpy` would be better as the first operation, or just use `sprintf` to do the whole thing at once, rather than a `strcpy/multiple-strcat` sequence.

And, finally, a command passed to `system` does not need a trailing newline.

A better method may be something like:

```
static const char prefix[] = "cp mediaPlayer.exe ";
char *chain1 = malloc(sizeof(prefix) + strlen(actual->chain));
if (chain1 != NULL) {
    sprintf(chain1, "%s%s", prefix, actual1->chain);
}
```

Space for the terminating `\0` is accounted for my using `sizeof` on the string rather than `strlen`. The former includes space for the terminator. And note the check for a failed `malloc`, this is something you should *always* do if you want robust code. I shouldn't need to mention that, should `chain1` end up being `NULL` at the end of this code block, you should *not* pass it to `system`.

Answer (score 2):

In your code the `malloc` size has nothing to do with the data you are putting into it.

You need

```
size_t len = strlen("cp mediaPlayer.exe ") + 
             strlen(actual->chain) +
             strlen("\n") + 1; // +1 for terminating 0.
chain1 = malloc(len);
```

After that your first `strcat` may fail because the allocated buffer may not (probably won't) contain a null terminated string. Either add `chain[0] = 0;` or change the first `strcat` to `strcpy`.